# Proving Roots by Theorems

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Prove that the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x+\frac{1}{4}$ has at least one root on the interval $[0,1]$, by using the Mean Value Theorem.

---

Since we know that polynomials are continuous every where, $p(x)$ is continuous.

Mean Value Theorem for Integrals: Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $g:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be integrable, and $g\geq 0$ on $[a,b]$. Then $\exists c\in[a,b] $ such that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)  dx = f(c)\int_a^b g(x)  dx$

Corollary: select $g(x)=1$ on $[a,b]$.  If $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere, then there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)  dx = f(c)(b-a)$.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do using the intermediate value theorem since $p(0)>0$ and $p(1/2)<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\int\limits_0^1 p(x) dx = \left. \frac14 x^4 - \frac12 x^2 + \frac14 x \right|_0^1 = 0$$

So by the mean value theorem, there exists a $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that
$$p(\xi)=\int\limits_0^1 p(x) dx=0.$$